# Issue with Arduino car bot, the servo motor moves randomly also it turns hot pretty quickly

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, shields

I trying to create an Arduino avoiding obstacle car. Using Arduino Uno +shield (sensor sheild v5.0). The problem is that when I upload the code, the servo moves randomly (it doesn't rotate to the right) and becomes hot quickly, it is an SG90 with 5v. I have already checked several times and the hardware seems all right.

I have tried to change the angle of the servo, checked the pins several times - uploaded the code many times I have also used serial.prints. researched on the internet.

```cpp
#include <NewPing.h>        //Ultrasonic sensor function library. You must install this library

//our L298N control pins
const int LeftMotorForward = 5;
const int LeftMotorBackward = 4;
const int RightMotorForward = 1;
const int RightMotorBackward = 0;

//sensor pins
#define trig_pin A1 //analog input 1
#define echo_pin A2 //analog input 2

#define maximum_distance 200
boolean goesForward = false;
int distance = 100;

NewPing sonar(trig_pin, echo_pin, maximum_distance); //sensor function
Servo servo_motor; //our servo name

void setup(){

  pinMode(RightMotorForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LeftMotorForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LeftMotorBackward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RightMotorBackward, OUTPUT);

  servo_motor.attach(11); //our servo pin

  servo_motor.write(90);
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}

void loop(){

  int distanceRight = 0;
  int distanceLeft = 0;
  delay(50);

  if (distance <= 20){
    moveStop();
    delay(300);
    moveBackward();
    delay(400);
    moveStop();
    delay(300);
    distanceRight = lookRight();
    delay(300);
    distanceLeft = lookLeft();
    delay(300);

    if (distance >= distanceLeft){
      turnRight();
      moveStop();
    }
    else{
      turnLeft();
      moveStop();
    }
  }
  else{
    moveForward(); 
  }
    distance = readPing();
}

int lookRight(){  
  servo_motor.write(10);
  delay(500);
  int distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  servo_motor.write(90);
  return distance;
}

int lookLeft(){
  servo_motor.write(170);
  delay(500);
  int distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  servo_motor.write(90);
  return distance;
  delay(100);
}

int readPing(){
  delay(70);
  int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
  if (cm==0){
    cm=250;
  }
  return cm;
}

void moveStop(){

  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
}

void moveForward(){

  if(!goesForward){

    goesForward=true;

    digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW); 
  }
}

void moveBackward(){

  goesForward=false;

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);

}

void turnRight(){

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);



}

void turnLeft(){

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);
}
```

Expected to the servo to rotate 90 degrees, but right now the servo is moving randomly.

Comment: If the motor gets hot quickly, there is something broken or it is connected wrong. Please show us your circuit. Are you sure about the polarity of the servos supply voltage?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do some rigorous testing of the individual functions of your bot.

Step 1: rename your loop function to "loop_temp" which means it won't run, but it will be retained for later.

Step 2: write a new "loop" function, which sets the LeftMotorForward for 1 second, then stop for 1 second.  And observe the results.

Step 3: repeat Step 2 with LeftMotorBackward, RightMotorForward, etc

Step 4: using serial print, experiment with the output from the sonar to make sure it's delivering the expected results.

Step 5: one at a time introduce your functions and ensure they are each working properly.

Step 6: hopefully you've discovered a bug/fault somewhere, and you can re-introduce your original "loop" function.  Otherwise that function may be the issue.

I've had a look at your code, but don't see anything obviously amiss.  So I'm afraid it may be a process of elimination.